# DCOM Config for Office 365

Tags: python, windows, iis, ms-word, office-automation

I have a Windows Server EC2 on AWS with Office 365 installed. I am running Django on IIS running under NetworkService and using a Python library docx2pdf to convert a docx to pdf.

Unfortunately I get an Access Denied error trying to do this. I have seen elsewhere where it is recommended to add permissions within DCOM Config (https://www.ryadel.com/en/office-interop-dcom-config-windows-server-iis-word-excel-access-asp-net-c-sharp/ for example). However I cannot see Microsoft Word listed here (I have tried looking in both 32 and 64 bit versions, and restarted the instance following installing Office). Am I on the right track and if so how do I locate this component?

Answer (score 0):

The [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) states the following:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Consider using the Open XML SDK if you deal with open XML documents only, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information. Also you may consider using third-party components designed for the server-side execution.